# UK self assessment : Declare childcare vouchers?

Tags: taxes, income-tax, united-kingdom

I'm trying to fill in my self assessment form for UK Tax.

Now my P60 declares the figures of..

```
"Pay in this period" of  "50k"  

"Tax in this period" of  "12k"
```

(Note figures have been changed)

Now I also do salary sacrifice for pension and childcare vouchers (500 & 124 a month each).

My question is...

when filling in the value for `"Pay from ABCD Ltd - total from your P45 or P60. Enter the amount before tax taken off:"`

Do I put in 50k or do I take off the 124+500*12 (£7488) from the 50k?

I didn't pay tax on this amount, 7488, since it's taken before tax.

So do I subtract it or not?

Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your P60 will already be net of the pension and childcare vouchers - i.e. the 50k is the value after they are taken off.

From the point of view of your tax return just ignore them completely and enter the figures from the P60 directly.

Comment: Thanks. I suspect that my P60 might be incorrect, I will follow this up. P60 shows my Contractual salary, not the value of what I was paid after KiddiVouchers&Pension were taken off. Thanks for confirming what I suspect though.

Comment: Technically if you're using "salary sacrifice" to make these contributions then you are agreeing to a contract variation where that amount is taken off your salary. However I imagine you know what the headline total should be :-)

Comment: If they really have screwed this up, something quite serious has gone wrong. Go back over your payslips for the year and see if the total taxable income adds up to the P60 amount or not, and similarly for the tax paid. Then check that the tax paid on the P60 is the right amount for the taxable income stated there. Also check whether you actually received what your payslips imply you should and whether they add up generally. If they've got this wrong, something won't add up somewhere in that lot...

Comment: Thanks for the comments Ganesh. Seems P60 is correct, error was due to when I started and a mid year salary change. My Mistake, thanks again for you help though.